# Combining video and audio from multiple sources using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

I am trying to add an audio file to a video file using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "Video.avi" -i "Wave.wav" -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy "Output.mp4"
```

The above parameters work but the output file length is the greater of the two input lengths. How can I specify using the video's length instead?

Comment: If your video is 10mn long, you can use -t 10:00. That will drop anything that comes after the 10mn mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been noted [[1]](https://superuser.com/a/570729)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31356896#comment50695635_31356896), in many cases FFmpeg cannot
accurately set the duration, or will not set duration as would be expected. Use
`-t` to set desired duration.